# I want to debug mysql server

Tags: mysql, xcode, debugging, gdb

I am developing storage engine for mysql. I need to know flow of mysql server. so I want to debug mysql server statement by statement in xcode or GNU debugger. Any body will help me to build n run mysql in debug mode.

Comment: Are you sure that is the right approach to start with? Usually when developing "plugins" in any form for an existing framework one does _not_ have to debug like that. Instead one takes the documentation of the plugin interface... You _have_ worked through the documentation MySQL offers? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/custom-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps which helps you to debug mysql in xcode.
http://technicalqueriess.blogspot.in/2016/04/1-donwload-mysql5.html